# How to kill w3wp.exe conclusively (IIS8, Win Server 2012)?

Tags: iis

Whenever I kill process `w3wp.exe`, it's being recreated anew. It's a child of `svchost.exe`. Even stopping the IIS using the IIS Manager leaves it alive. How come ?

It is in IIS-8, Windows server 2012

Comment: Can't you just uninstall IIS (or disable the feature/role for Application Server/Web IIS?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in inetmgr.msc, you need to stop the application pool.

look at the commandline for the w3wp.exe in question, to determine which app pool you wish to stop. you can use a tool like Process Explorer to view the process commandline, by double-clicking the process.

then in inetmgr.msc, expand the tree and go to "Application Pools". find the correct pool, and Right-click -> Stop.

you will likely have to disable the WWW service in order to prevent it from starting again at next boot. use services.msc to do this.